# Getting started with Sphinx when your source files aren't in the project base folder

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, sphinx-apidoc

Alright, I've been struggling with Sphinx not producing any documentation from the docstrings I've written in this example code. Its a simple implementation of a stack in Python.

You probably need not read all of this:

`src/stack.py`

```
class Stack:
    """Stack
    A simple implementation of a stack data structure in Python.

    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = []

    def push(self,item):
        """Push

        Push an item on to the stack.

        Args:
            arg: Item to be pushed to the top of the stack
        """
        self._data.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        """Pop

        Pop the top item off from the stack and return it.

        Returns:
            element: Item at the top of the stack.
        """
        item = self._data[-1]
        self._data = self._data[:-1]
        return item

    def pop_n(self,n):
        """Pop n elements

        Pops the top n elements from the stack.

        Parameters
        ----------
        arg1 : int
            Number of elements to be popped from the top of the stack

        Returns
        -------
        list
            A list of the top n elements popped from the stack
        """
        items = []
        for i in range(0,n):
            items.append(self.pop())
        return items

    def multipop(self):
        """Multipop

        Pops all the elements from the stack

        Returns
        -------
        list
            A list of every element in the stack
        """
        items = []
        while self.size() > 0:
            items.append(self.pop())
        return items

    def size(self):
        """Get Size

        Determine the size of the stack

        Returns
        -------
        int: A count of elements on the stack
        """
        return len(self._data)
```

`conf.py`

```
# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..')) # original path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../src')) # 2020-1-31 edited path

# ... A few inconsequential default settings and author information here ...
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc',
              'sphinx.ext.coverage',
              'sphinx.ext.napoleon'
             ]
```

`stack.rst`

```
stack module
============

.. automodule:: stack
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

I've attemped to use Sphinx to document this code with the command `$ sphinx-autodoc -o docs/source src/`. This outputs the files `modules.rst, stack.rst`. Then I `sphinx-build` the output into HTML from my makefile.

My output is a header on an empty page: **Stack Module**

[like this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkfPw.png)

Is something *automatic* supposed to be happening here? How do I get any meaningful output from using Sphinx autodoc?

2020-1-31 Update: I'm still having some trouble with this, so I followed the suggestions of Masklinn and created a [Github repository](https://github.com/MisterEncryptor/sphinx-stack-and-doc) in addition to the other suggestion of changing the path as mentioned, but the documentation output is still unsatisfactory.

2020-2-11 Update: The file structure I'm dealing with

```
.
├── docs
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── doctrees
│   │   │   ├── environment.pickle
│   │   │   ├── index.doctree
│   │   │   ├── modules.doctree
│   │   │   └── src.doctree
│   │   └── html
│   │       └── ... (misc html stuff)
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── index.rst
│   ├── make.bat
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── modules.rst
│   └── src.rst
├── Readme.md
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    └── stack.py
```